# Unable to import Java class in Android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Here is my directory structure within the "java" folder,

[image]

The problem is in my `MainActivity` file when I write.

```
import api.gitapi;
import model.gitmodel;
```

I get a warning message saying "Unused Import"

In my `MainActivity` file, I get an error on line,

```
gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);
```

and,

```
public void success(gitmodel gitmodel, Response response) {}
```

saying that the symbol `gitapi` and `gitmodel` cannot be resolved. I have tried "Invalidate caches/restart" but the problem still exists.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

PS: If it helps, I'm using **[this tutorial](http://themakeinfo.com/2015/04/retrofit-android-tutorial/)**

Comment: It looks like `gitapi` and `gitmodel` are in a test-specific source folder as opposed to the main source folder, according to the screenshot. Is that expected based on the tutorial?

Comment: @hexafraction It does not specifically says anything about that, I just right clicked on "java" and then clicked "package" to create a new package. Is there a way through which I can create package in the main source folder?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure; I would need to go through the tutorial carefully. Please check in your normal, non-IDE-specific file explorer as to whether the folder layout is in fact as shown, or if the IDE is collapsing some of the structure to simplify the presented data.

Comment: @hexafraction Great! this solved my problem, I had to select to create a package on the main source folder. Thanks, can you post this as an answer so that I can select it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Posted, happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have placed the `gitapi` and `gitmodel` classes into a test source folder, meaning that they are available to be imported by other classes in the test folder, but not in the main folder (where your activity lives). Create those classes in the main source folder and your activity will be able to import and reference them.

Answer (score 0):

just need to refract the classes into the package containing MainActivity.class and it might solve your problem and you will get the result what you want.